# Update JSONObject on Android JSCORE

Tags: javascript, java, android, json

I'm using the Android JSCore
https://github.com/ericwlange/AndroidJSCore

The issue is as follows:

I have a JS function, something like: (function(javaFunction) {javaFunction.setValue(someJson, field,value);})

So I implemented this javaFunction on my android project but the issue is that I have to read the someJson object as JSObject and some the function looks like this

```
public JSFUnction setValue(){
JSFUNCTION myJavaFunction = new JSFunction(someContext, "setValue"){
public void setValue (JSObject myJson,string field, string value){
   JSONObject js= new JSONObject(myJson.toJson());
   js.put(field,value); /// No way to update the JSObject with the value now is js}}}
```

but I can't update myJson with the new value.. I pass a reference to the function, I can extract the Json within but I can't update it and put it back to the JSObject..

Can you assist me with this issue? Can  I update the JSONObject within the JSObject (because the function has to be void and work on the reference.. and the JSObject seems to be readonly..)

Thanks